# common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Invalid id: [] How to remove [] parenthesis when LWC sends List of Ids to controller class method?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-web-components, controller, json

I have created Custom List Button on Case object. That button calls VF page and then VF page calls LWC which updates the record. Once Record is updated I want to navigate back to Current List View. I have tried below code:

**VF Page:**

```
   <apex:page standardController="Case" recordSetVar="cs" extensions="PassSelectedIdsToFlowVFController">
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="lightning" />
    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:changeOwnerLWCOnListApp", function() {
             $Lightning.createComponent("c:changeOwnerLWCOnList", {
                recordListId: {!SelectedCaseIDsJSON}
                 },
              "lightning",
              function(cmp) {
                console.log("LWC component was created");
                // do some stuff
              }
          );
        });
    </script>
    
</apex:page>
```

**Controller Class:**

```
public without sharing class PassSelectedIdsToFlowVFController {
    public List<String> SelectedCaseIDs{get;set;}
    //This will give List of Records which is selected from List View
    public PassSelectedIdsToFlowVFController(ApexPages.StandardSetController listcontroller){
        SelectedCaseIDs = new List<String>();
        for(Case acc : (Case[])listcontroller.getSelected()){
            System.debug('Case Id:'+acc.Id);
            SelectedCaseIDs.add(acc.Id);
        }
        system.debug('SelectedCaseIDs:'+SelectedCaseIDs);
    }
    //THis method will update records and accept parameters from LWC
    @AuraEnabled
    public static string updateOwner(List<String> recordListIds){
        System.debug('recordListId is:'+recordListIds);
        //List<String> values = (List<String>) JSON.deserialize(recordListIds,List<String>); Tried to something like this but its not working
        List<Id> cseIds = new List<Id>();
        Map<Id,Case> mapToUpdate = new Map<Id,Case>();
        try{
            for(Case cse: [Select Id,ownerId from Case where Id IN:recordListIds]){
                system.debug('Current User:'+ userInfo.getUserId());
                cse.ownerId = userInfo.getUserId();
                mapToUpdate.put(cse.Id,cse);
            }
            if(!mapToUpdate.isEmpty()){
                system.debug('mapToUpdate size:'+mapToUpdate.size());
                update mapToUpdate.values();
                return 'success';
            }
            else{
                return 'Fail';
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.debug('Exception is:'+ex.getMessage());
            return 'Fail';
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

**LWC JS File:**

```
    import {
    LightningElement,
    track,
    api,
    wire
} from 'lwc';
import {
    ShowToastEvent
} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import {
    NavigationMixin
} from 'lightning/navigation';
import updateOwner from '@salesforce/apex/PassSelectedIdsToFlowVFController.updateOwner';
export default class ChangeOwnerLWCOnList extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordListId = [];
    @track recordListIds = [];
    connectedCallback() {
        this.recordListIds = this.recordListId;
        console.log('recordListId:' + JSON.stringify(this.recordListId));
        console.log('recordListIds:' + this.recordListIds);
        updateOwner({
                recordListIds: this.recordListIds
            })
            .then(result => {
                    console.log('Result is:' + result);
                    if (result == 'Success') {
                        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                            type: 'standard__objectPage',
                            attributes: {
                                objectApiName: 'Case',
                                actionName: 'list'
                            },
                            state: {
                                filterName: 'Recent'
                            },
                        });
                        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Toast Success',
                            message: 'Owner is Changed Successfully',
                            variant: 'success',
                            mode: 'dismissable'
                        });
                        this.dispatchEvent(evt);

                        this.error = undefined;
                    } else if (result == 'Fail') {
                        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Toast Error',
                            message: 'Some unexpected error',
                            variant: 'error',
                            mode: 'dismissable'
                        });
                        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
                    }
                }

            )
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
                const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Toast Error',
                    message: 'Some unexpected error',
                    variant: 'error',
                    mode: 'dismissable'
                });
                this.dispatchEvent(evt);
                this.contacts = undefined;
            });
    }
}
```

When I checked debug logs then I am getting List of records id which I selected Like this:
**([5006F00001lcGWGQA2, 5006F00001lcGWUQA2])**
while it should display like this **(5006F00001lcGWGQA2, 5006F00001lcGWUQA2)**

I am not sure why bracket [] is appearing when I pass List of Records from LWC to Controller Class
due to which I am getting **common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Invalid id: [5006F00001lcGWGQA2, 5006F00001lcGWUQA2]**

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Visualforce Page:

```
recordListId: '{!SelectedCaseIDs}'
```

This is a string, not an Array; that's your problem. You need to serialize this in your JavaScript:

```
// Pass this in as a List of ID values
recordListId: {!SelectedCaseIDsJSON}
```

...

```
public without sharing class PassSelectedIdsToFlowVFController {
  public List<String> SelectedCaseIDs{get;set;}
  // Serialize SelectedCaseIDs so it comes out as an object in JavaScript
  public String getSelectedCaseIDSJSON() {
    return JSON.serialize(SelectedCaseIDs);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks you so much ! This is working as expected but when I navigate back to list view then its not working. I have updated LWC file and added NavigationMixin code there but its not navigating back. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong there?

Comment: @DhananjayPatil NavigationMixin only works in proper Lightning, not a Visualforce page. You'd want to use window.location or window.history to navigate back to the list view, something like `window.top.location = '/500/o'`

Comment: Thanks Again @sfdcfox

Comment: I was able to navigate to List View from VF which calls LWC however I could not see updated value in List View records. If i refresh the LIst view manually, I am able to see updated values. I tried with sforce.one.back(true) but its not working. Is this limitation or is there any workaround for this?